# Is it possible to display UILabel.attributedText in a storyboard using @IBDesignable?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

All the labels in my app are using fonts with spacing/kerning values set as well as colors and several other things and I want to see what thing look like in the storyboard with all of these attributes applied.

As UILabel is a UIView I was hoping it might be possible to achieve this by using @IBDesignable. But after some experimentation I can't get anything to happen in the storyboard.

This is the code:

```
@IBDesignable class CustomLabel: UILabel {
    @IBDesignable override var text: String? {
        didSet {
            guard let text = text else { return }
            let titleAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.green]
            let titleString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text, attributes: titleAttributes)
            titleString.addAttribute(NSKernAttributeName, value: 5, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: text.characters.count))
            // Other attributes
            self.attributedText = titleString
        }
    }
}
```

...

```
@IBOutlet weak var theTitle: CustomLabel!
theTitle.text = "Some stuff"
```

But in the storyboard the label is displayed without any of the attributed string settings applied.

Does anybody know if what I'm attempting is going to be possible, and if so how to get it working?

Comment: Here's hoping you get an answer that show you can. I wish I could use IB to show **true** portrait versus landscape views (size classes do not work for iPad) but due to a restriction that basically says "you cannot **execute** code in IB "design mode"" I ended up doing things (more and more) in code. Eventually My views in IB ended up blank - why use it? My bottom line of thought? You are using "logical code" to attempt to be displayed in IB. How can you expect IB ("IBDesignable") to execute it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Swift 3**

As per Your situation use **@IBInspectable**  to *overridden text var* of **UILabel** , This will allow you to pass the text from property inspector (see screen shot) which will be rendered on Storyboard

[image]

```
@IBDesignable class DGlabel: UILabel {

@IBInspectable override var text: String? {
    didSet {
        decorate()
    }
}

@IBInspectable var fontSize: CFloat = 15 {
    didSet {
        decorate()
    }
}


@IBInspectable var fontColor: UIColor = UIColor.red {
    didSet {
        decorate()
    }
}

/*** more inspectable var can be added **/

func decorate() {

    guard let text = text else { return }

    let titleAttributes = [
        NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: fontSize),
        NSForegroundColorAttributeName : fontColor,
        NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue
        ] as [String : Any]

    let titleString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text, attributes: titleAttributes)

    // Other attributes
    titleString.addAttribute(NSKernAttributeName, value: 5, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: text.characters.count))

    self.attributedText = titleString
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Essenceofchicken My pleasure :)

Comment: Do you know if it easily possible to expand this in such a way that the content of decorate can be variable, i.e. for some labels the font size is 15, or others its 16, for others its 17 and so one, sometimes the color is red sometimes white and so on?